# How Do I "Mix/Superimpose" two m4a audio files together

Tags: ios, audio, background-music

After finally successfully finding a way to concatenate multiple voice files into one single audio file on the iPhone, I am am now trying to superimpose an audio file over the length of the voice file.

So basically I have two `.m4a` files:

1. voice.m4a which is about 10 seconds for example.
2. music.m4a which is about 5 seconds.

What I require is that two file be combined in such a manner that the resulting *single* audio file now contains the music in the background of the voice file for the length of it, so basically the resulting output should have the 10 seconds of voice and the 5seconds of music repeated twice. It is absolutely important to have a single file that contains all of this.

I am trying to get all of this done in an application on the iPhone.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Use Audacity. It's a good freeware audio editor.

Comment: urrgghhhH!!!! I have been so caught up with this that I thought people would know what I am talking about, my Bad. I need this done on the iphone, let me edit the question..

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do that programmatically, you will need to go deeper down into CoreAudio. For a simpler solution you could use AudioQueues or for more fine grained control AudioUnits and an AUGraph. The MultiChannelMixer is the Audio Unit you are looking for. Unfortunately there is no space for an elaborate tutorial here (would take a couple of days to write just the tutorial itself), but I am hoping I could point you to the right direction.

If you decide to go down that path and want to do further audio programming then this one time simple example, then I strongly suggest you buy "Learning Core Audio, A Hands-on Guide to Audio Programming for Mac and iOS" - Chris Adamson, Kevin Avila. You can find it on Amazon, paperback or Kindle.